# Searching for a matched string within nested cell and delivering the index

Tags: matlab, cell, matching

I have a nested cell array which is called
`values`. [Description as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6lWu.png). In this example, there are 5 sub cells. Usually this number is variable from 1 to 30. Each cell has two subsub cells:

1. he first one, or `values{5,1}{1,1}`, has always only one char value
   (in this example, `TOTAL` or `MGS`)
2. the second one, or `values{5,1}{2,1}`, has matrix consisting from tow columns: on the left - tempearature values, on the right - physical properties.

My goal is to find the sub cell containing the char value `'TOTAL'` (`values{5,1}`) and somehow to get the index of the matrix (the output would be `values{5,1}{2,1}`)

To adress the challenge, I have written my handmade solution. This code works if there is in the char `'TOTAL'` in `a{5,1}{1,1}` and takes a corresponding value next to 298.15 K. However, the string `'TOTAL'` could be elsewhere. In this case, I have a problem. In this solution, the double loop takes long time. So, do you have another solution how to find the index of a cell with `'TOTAL'` avoiding loops?

```
    for m = 1:numel(values)
        for n = 1:numel(values(m))
            a = values(m);
            if string(a{5,1}{1,1}) == 'TOTAL'
                k = a{5,1}{2,1}(:,1); %column with temp numbers
                n = 298.15;           %RT
                [~,~,idx] = unique(round(abs(k-n)));
                minVal = k(idx==1);
                valueAtRT = sprintf('%f', a{1,1}{5,1}(length(a{1,1}{5,1})+idx));
                break;
            end
        end
    end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What you have done thus far is given a problem description, which is great, but what you haven't done is **asked a question**. At present, this question reads like a rude problem dump, asking us to do your work for you. I'm sure you've already done something, so please [edit] the question to show your thought process into solving this problem and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advices. Are my edits sufficient to reopen my question?

Comment: Yes, I've voted as such. One thing though, you have asked 2 questions, of which the second is a bit broad. Just "how can I improve this" is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, I'd remove it and focus on the first question (preferably add a [mcve] there as well). If you really want help on improving it, profile the code, mention specifically what's slow and what you attempted to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution assuming there is only one cell with `'TOTAL'`:

```
is = cellfun( @(cac) strcmp(cac{1},'TOTAL'), values, 'uniformoutput',false  );
num = values{is}{2};
valueAtRT = interp1( num(:,1), num(:,2), 298.15, 'nearest', 'extrap' );
```

`is` delivers the index of the cell, where the char `'TOTAL'` is stored and the third line delivers the value next to 298.15.